# Local web proxy for Windows to route through VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, proxy

I am looking for a program for Windows 7 similar to FreeProxy that will allow the following:

I want the program to listen on a local port (eg. 1337) and act as a proxy server. For all traffic sent to 127.0.0.1:1337, I want the program to route that traffic through a VPN connection that I have set up. Since my VPN connection is set up to not be the default gateway of my machine, that means that any traffic not sent through the program will be outside the VPN connection.

Is there any program that would be able to do this?